# Bot Framework v4 welcome message in Webchat Channel

Tags: botframework, chatbot, web-chat

I am working with Bot framework v4 webchat, trying to send a welcome message when a bot is initialized. First i send an event activity to the bot from webchat channel and got a 200 status response from but i can't able to capture the event activity in OneventActivityAsync action.

I have go though the below given solution.

https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/04.api/a.welcome-event

**OneventActivityAsync Section:**

```
    if (turnContext.Activity.Name == "webchat/join")
     {
         await turnContext.SendActivityAsync("Welcome Message!");
     }
```

Could anyone help me on this?

I really appreciate any help :)

Answer (score 0):

Your approach should work for v3. But for v4 you need to handle this event in OnMembersAddedAsync method.

```
protected override async Task OnMembersAddedAsync(IList<ChannelAccount> membersAdded, ITur

nContext<IConversationUpdateActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        if (turnContext.Activity.ChannelId != "webchat" && turnContext.Activity.ChannelId != "directline") {
    
            foreach (var member in membersAdded)
            {
                if (member.Id != turnContext.Activity.Recipient.Id)
                {
                    await turnContext.SendActivityAsync("Welcome");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Br,
Pdeepa

Comment: @pdeepa, I have already checked this, but event activity is not triggered in bot server side.

Comment: This should trigger. Does it work if you use a [sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/03.welcome-user) instead of your bot?